# Supervised genstage worker on genstage documentation not working correctly?

Tags: elixir, erlang-supervisor, genstage

At https://hexdocs.pm/gen_stage/GenStage.html#module-init-and-subscribe_to I define the GenStage modules with `subscribe_to` option

```
defmodule A do
  use GenStage

  def start_link(number) do
    GenStage.start_link(A, number)
  end

  def init(counter) do
    {:producer, counter}
  end

  def handle_demand(demand, counter) when demand > 0 do
    # If the counter is 3 and we ask for 2 items, we will
    # emit the items 3 and 4, and set the state to 5.
    events = Enum.to_list(counter..counter+demand-1)
    {:noreply, events, counter + demand}
  end
end

defmodule B do
  use GenStage

  def start_link(number) do
    GenStage.start_link(B, number)
  end

  def init(number) do
    {:producer_consumer, number, subscribe_to: [{A, max_demand: 10}]}
  end

  def handle_events(events, _from, number) do
    events = Enum.map(events, & &1 * number)
    {:noreply, events, number}
  end
end

defmodule C do
  use GenStage

  def start_link() do
    GenStage.start_link(C, :ok)
  end

  def init(:ok) do
    {:consumer, :the_state_does_not_matter, subscribe_to: [B]}
  end

  def handle_events(events, _from, state) do
    # Wait for a second.
    Process.sleep(1000)

    # Inspect the events.
    IO.inspect(events)

    # We are a consumer, so we would never emit items.
    {:noreply, [], state}
  end
end
```

If I run them manually it works

```
iex(1)> GenStage.start_link(A, 0, name: A)
{:ok, #PID<0.195.0>}
iex(2)> GenStage.start_link(B, 2, name: B)
{:ok, #PID<0.197.0>}
iex(3)> GenStage.start_link(C, :ok)
{:ok, #PID<0.199.0>}
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
[10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
[20, 22, 24, 26, 28]
[30, 32, 34, 36, 38]
‘(*,.0’
```

Then it suggest it can be added in a supervisor tree:

> In a supervision tree, this is often done by starting multiple
>   workers:

```
defmodule TestDep.Application do
  @moduledoc false

  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    import Supervisor.Spec

    children = [
      worker(A, [0]),
      worker(B, [2]),
      worker(C, []),
    ]
    opts = [strategy: :rest_for_one]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end
end
```

That’s my supervisor tree but when running the app with `iex -S mix` I receive a:

> ** (Mix) Could not start application testdep: TestDep.Application.start(:normal, []) returned an error: shutdown:
>   failed to start child: B
>   ** (EXIT) no process: the process is not alive or there’s no process currently associated with the given name, possibly because its
>   application isn’t started

My app is defined on `mix.ex` as

```
def application do
[
extra_applications: [:logger],
mod: {TestDep.Application, []}
]
end
```

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I run them manually it works

It does not :(
What works is not what you wanted to test and is not the equivalent of what you are starting in the supervision tree, this is:

```
A.start_link(0)
B.start_link(2)
C.start_link()
```

---

That said, you likely want to pass *names* to wrapped `GenStage.start_link`:

```
defmodule A do
  use GenStage

  def start_link(number) do
    #                            ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓ THIS
    GenStage.start_link(A, number, name: A)
  end
```

And the same for the rest.

Comment: that was it, the doc only tells you to modify init() method and you can call the GenStage.start_link(A, 0, name: A) method with the process name, but doesnt explicitly says to update the start_link method... not sure if consider it incomplete or not (for dummies like me)

Comment: Well, the documentation on [`GenStage.init/1#consumer-and-producer_consumer-options`](https://hexdocs.pm/gen_stage/GenStage.html#c:init/1-consumer-and-producer_consumer-options) is a bit confusing, since it does not mention it should be _module name_ rather name _module_, silently assuming every `GenServer` is started by default with `name: __MODULE__` argument.

Comment: One question, this wouldnt be needed for the consumer right? (module C) as they won't be subscribed to. I have tested this just updating module A and B and works.

Comment: The only reason it’s needed is the ability to refer to the `GenServer` by it’s name. Your code does it in `B` (referring to `A`: `subscribe_to: [{A, max_demand: 10}]`) and in `C` (referring to `B`; `subscribe_to: [B]`.) So you don’t need the named `C`, but it’s a good habit to `name: __MODULE__` _everywhere_.